# Merge Multiple Word Documents while Preserving Headers - .Net Office Automation

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to merge multiple word documents while preserving the header and footer of each document. The below code is merging the documents but merges the header and the footer as well:

```
public static void Merge(List filesToMerge, string outputFilename)
{
    Application wordApplication = null;
    Document wordDocument = null;

    try
    {
        // Create a new Microsoft Word application object
        wordApplication = new Application();
        wordApplication.Visible = false;
        wordApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;

        // Create a new file based on our template
        object defaultTemplate = @"Normal.dotm";
        wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(ref defaultTemplate);

        // Make a Word selection object.
        Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;

        // Loop thru each of the Word documents
        foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
        {
            // Insert the files to our template
            selection.InsertFile(file);
            object pageBreak = WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
            selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);
        }

        // Save the document to it's output file.
        object outputFile = outputFilename;
        wordDocument.SaveAs(ref outputFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error while conversion. Details: " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        MSWordCleanup(wordApplication, wordDocument);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you to work through these training lessons:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/headers-and-footers-from-basic-to-elaborate-RZ001021662.aspx

While this won't give you the answer in "automation form", it might be enough for you to figure out the answer.

Comment: Thanks, for sharing the training lessons.
Sections breaks should be enough to ensure different headers and footers but in my case I have one document that doesn't have any header or footer but when merged, it takes the header and footer from the previous page. Any idea how to keep this page without headers and footers?

Comment: @sh_kamalh I'm afraid that I've never done anything "elaborate" with headers/footers in Word, that's why my inclination was to look to the Office help. I can only make guesses. Have you tried adding a dummy header when there is none and removing it afterwords?